# Putting a default image into a Javascript IFRAME

Tags: javascript, iframe

So I am working on my site and I have made this IFRAME :

```
<IFRAME src="" width="100%" height="80%" id="productarea" name="productarea" frameborder="0" marginheight="0">
</IFRAME>
```

Now I want to put a deafult image so when the page loads, were the IFRAME is , there is an image. I have figured out how to do this by putting the URL to the image in the src="". Like so:

```
<IFRAME src="http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/Books-06.jpg" width="100%" height="80%" id="productarea" name="productarea" frameborder="0" marginheight="0">
    </IFRAME>
```

Now my issue is that when the image is loaded I cant get it to load in the center of the page. It always just goes to the left. My other issue is that once the image is loaded,when I call a function that will load html into my Iframe, nothing happens, the image just remains there. Any ideas how to resolve these issues?

Answer (score 0):

> Now my issue is that when the image is loaded I cant get it to load in the center of the page. It always just goes to the left.

That is what happens when you load images. If you want to do any layout, then load an HTML document containing the image and a stylesheet instead.

> My other issue is that once the image is loaded,when I call a function that will load html into my Iframe, nothing happens, the image just remains there.

Something is wrong with the code you haven't shared with us. We can't tell what, we can't see the code.

You can replace whatever it is with the standard way to load new HTML into a frame:

```
<a href="url-to-html" target="name_of_frame">example</a>
```